# Why is this code not drawing a line?

Tags: java

I am not sure why my code is not working but it is driving me crazy.

This is my class that should draw the button and creates the area to draw on:

The second set of code is the driver program I need to make 4 canvas's that when I make two mouse clicks it draws a line between the two clicks and then repaints if I try and click on a canvas again.

I get the following errors: 
error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    addMouseListener(this);
    ^
 error: illegal start of type
    addMouseListener(this);
                     ^

```
public class Scribble extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
addMouseListener(this);
int x, x1, y, y1;
boolean flag = false;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
}


public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{

    if (!flag){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        flag = true;
    }
    else{
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();
        flag = false;
        repaint();
}
}



public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}

}



public class Lab8Draw extends JFrame{

public Lab8Draw(){
    Color c = new Color(100, 10, 200);
    setTitle("Lab 8 - Application #1");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    Scribble s = new Scribble();
    s.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(s);
    Scribble s1 = new Scribble();
    s1.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(s1);
    Scribble s2 = new Scribble();
    s2.setBackground(c);
    add(s2);
    Scribble s3 = new Scribble();
    s.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    add(s3);

}


    public static void main (String[] args){


        Lab8Draw frame = new Lab8Draw();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement `MouseListener`

```
public class Scribble extends JPanel implements MouseListener
```

and register it

```
Scribble s = new Scribble();
s.addMouseListener(s);
```

The [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) provide a useful guide to writing a `MouseListener`.

Alternatively, you could define an inner class that extends [MouseInputAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MouseInputAdapter.html) as it already has empty implementations of the `MouseListener` methods.

Comment: error: Scribble is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseEntered(MouseEvent) in MouseListener
public class Scribble extends JPanel implements MouseListener
       ^

Comment: You must implement all the methods prescribed on the _MouseListener_ interface. It's usually easiest to do this via your IDE (source->override/implement in Eclipse). It's fine if these are empty implementations (don't actually do anything), but you must have them defined!

Comment: We are not allowed to use ide's on our homework. Our instructor makes us use textpad

Comment: Haha that's awesome. And it's a good learning experience. It's even recommended when studying for your Java certification exams. In that case, you're better off going straight to the API for _MouseListener_ and copying the method signatures from there.

Comment: Ya I am going to get my certifications after my Java Application Programming 2 class I already bought the books to study so as soon as class is over I can pass the test.

Comment: Oh and you might want to tag this as homework if that's what it is?

Comment: In this case it's probably fine - it's more of a technical problem than asking to solve the problem you've been given.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to make your Scribble class extend JPanel. You also need to make your canvases call the addMouseListener method. Right now, all you really have is 4 canvases on a JFrame. You don't add the MouseListener to the panel inside that class. You add the listener to the *instance* of the Scribble class. Also, implement MouseListener *inside* of the driver class. You shouldn't do it in the JPanel class.

Comment: If you get an error, then just make that method empty like you did the others. MouseListener has 5 methods, not 4

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by implementing MouseListener inside of the driver class. I am currently implementing it on scribble . What do you mean by that?

Comment: I got it now I needed to add the addMouseListener to the constructor and I had it outside of it thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all the class `Scribble` must implements the `MouseListener`  and assign the event handlers via `addMouseListener`() method in order to capture mouse events. The MouseListener interface has following method that must be override.

```
class Scribble extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
  int x, x1, y, y1;
  boolean flag = false;
  public Scribble(){
   addMouseListener(this);
  }
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
  }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    if (!flag){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        flag = true;
    }
    else{
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();
        flag = false;
        repaint();
    }
  }
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: When I try and implement MouseListener I get error: Scribble is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseEntered(MouseEvent) in MouseListener
public class Scribble extends JPanel implements MouseListener

Comment: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
 addMouseListener(this);
 ^
 error: illegal start of type
 addMouseListener(this);

Comment: @user512915 - May be you are missing something. See my edited post.

Comment: Okay I missed adding it in the Constructor Thanks heaps it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add yourself as a MouseListener?  E.g.

this.addMouseListener(this);

Comment: error: illegal start of type
 this.addMouseListener(this);
 ^
 ';' expected
 this.addMouseListener(this);
     ^
 error: invalid method declaration; return type required
 this.addMouseListener(this);
      ^
 error: illegal start of type
 this.addMouseListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when the JPanels "Scribble" is drawn on the JFrame the coordinates are all 0, because they are not initialized. So you have a line from P(0/0) to P(0/0).

Check if your MouseListener is working....where do you register it? Don´t you need to implement MouseListener? Good luck.